# Extracting text with expressions from a text file using grep

Tags: bash, grep, sparse-files

I have the following 2 lines in my text file and wanted to calculate duration between those lines X & Y in minutes.

```
line X:  18.05.2022 13:54:52 [ INFO]: Starting Component 'OWN_FUNDS_RULES' (5/15)
line Y:  18.05.2022 14:28:22 [ INFO]: Finished Component 'OWN_FUNDS_RULES_CONSOLIDATION' (6/15) with SUCCESS - 00:07:05.119
```

I have the following code which is returning durations as zero.

```bsh
cd /logs/

Header="OFRComponentCalculation"
echo $Header >OutputFile.csv
for file in log_Job_*/process.log; do

    ### OFRComponentCalculation ###
    {
        OFRS="$(grep 'Starting Component*OWN_FUNDS_RULES*' "$file" | awk '{print $3,$4}' | cut -d: -f2-)"
        OFRE="$(grep 'Finished Component*OWN_FUNDS_RULES_CONSOLIDATION*' "$file" | awk '{print $1,$2}' | cut -d: -f1-)"

        convert_date() { printf '%s-%s-%s %s' ${1:6:4} ${1:3:2} ${1:0:2} ${1:11:8}; }

        # Convert to timestamp
        OFRS_TS=$(date -d "$(convert_date "$OFRS")" +%s)
        OFRE_TS=$(date -d "$(convert_date "$OFRE")" +%s)

        # Subtract
        OFRD=$((OFRS_TS - OFRE_TS))
        # convert to HH:MM:SS (note, that if it's more than one day, it will be wrong!)
        OFRComponentCalculation=$(date -u -d "@$OFRD" +%H:%M:%S)
        echo "$OFRComponentCalculation"
    }
    Var="$OFRComponentCalculation"
    echo $Var >>OutputFile.csv

done
```

I doubt am messing up something while writing grep commangs for these 2 line, can anyone help me.

Comment: Please edit your question and add what exactly do you want to see in the result.

Comment: @WhiteOwl I wanted to calculate the duration between line X and  line Y. I have grep commnds to fetch those times, but its not working as expected.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asking questions on text-processing, please be sure to always include a testable example, i.e. (possibly anonymized) example input along with the desired output, and any further information on the structure and formatting of the input file. That way, contributors can verify proposed solutions before posting them as answers.

Comment: If you want the date formated as `YYYY-MM-DD` you can just use something like this: `awk -F'[ :.]' '/OWN_FUNDS_RULES[^_]/ { print $7"-"$6"-"$5,$8":"$9 }'`, with gives you `2022-05-18 13:54`.

Comment: You seem to be confusing shell globs (where `*` is a "wildcard") with grep regular expressions (where `*` is a quantifier applied to the previous atom). See for example [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: `grep | awk` can almost always be condensed simply into `awk`

Comment: 1. don't define the function inside the loop. it only needs to be defined once, not every pass through the loop.  2. this is not a job for a shell script.  Perl would be a far better choice, as would awk.  See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
:~$ cat event.log
18.05.2022 13:54:52 [ INFO]: Starting Component 'OWN_FUNDS_RULES' (5/15)
18.05.2022 14:28:22 [ INFO]: Finished Component 'OWN_FUNDS_RULES_CONSOLIDATION' (6/15) with SUCCESS - 00:07:05.119

:~$ cat calc_time.sh
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"

OFRS="$(grep "Starting Component 'OWN_FUNDS_RULES'" "$file" | cut -d ' ' -f1,2)"
OFRE="$(grep "Finished Component 'OWN_FUNDS_RULES_CONSOLIDATION'" "$file" | cut -d ' ' -f1,2)"

function date_time {
        time_frame=$1
        day=$(echo $time_frame | cut -d '.' -f1 )
        month=$(echo $time_frame | cut -d '.' -f2 )
        year=$(echo $time_frame | cut -d '.' -f3 | cut -d ' ' -f1)
        hour=$(echo $time_frame | cut -d ' ' -f2 | cut -d ':' -f1)
        minute=$(echo $time_frame | cut -d ' ' -f2 | cut -d ':' -f2)
        second=$(echo $time_frame | cut -d ' ' -f2 | cut -d ':' -f3)
}

date_time "$OFRS"
sdate=$(date -d "$year"-"$month"-"$day"T"$hour":"$minute":"$second" +%s)
date_time "$OFRE"
fdate=$(date -d "$year"-"$month"-"$day"T"$hour":"$minute":"$second" +%s)

#Substraction
Exec_time=$(($fdate-$sdate))

echo Time of execution in seconds: $Exec_time
# convert to HH:MM:SS (note, that if it's more than one day, it will be wrong!)
OFRComponentCalculation=$(date -u -d "@$Exec_time" +%H:%M:%S)
echo "$OFRComponentCalculation"
```

You can then run it with the file as an argument:

```
:~$ bash calc_time.sh event.log
Time of execution in seconds: 2010
00:33:30
```

Comment: no need in awk at all, just wanted to show that to Manoj.

Comment: That should be 2010 seconds, not 2040.

Comment: Correct, I have corrected the script, the seconds were not counted

Comment: @DmitriyKupch : Thank you very much,